Hysteresis modelling as a control constraint for MPC in Python GEKKO
I am trying to introduce a hysteresis constraint in an MPC optimization problem for control signal dispatch using Python GEKKO. This has become a daunting task as I am unable to transform the following problem into equations that GEKKO understands.
The problem:

If ON time < minimum ON time, control dispatch for a given asset should not be able to turn it OFF.

If OFF time < minimum OFF time, control dispatch for the same asset should not be able to turn it ON.


An example of what I'm trying to do
Where:
engine = GEKKO(remote = False)

control = engine.Param(value = control_signal)

key        = engine.MV(value = 0)
key.STATUS =  1
key.LOWER  = -1
key.UPPER  =  1

engine.Equation(hysteresis_equation(key))

Manipulated variables in this case are dispatch percentiles of the control signal called 'key' which will influence the problem dynamics.
Where the key is the manipulated variable and hysteresis_equation is a function of the key value that should emulate a time dependent hysteresis. I have not given more details because there is no point, the problem resides in the implmentation of a non-linear hysteresis constraint in a GEKKO model.
I have tried looking at binary variables, however, I do not understand how to get them to change value throughout the optimization using GEKKO.
Tried calling an external function that returns True or False is not supported and yields @error: Equation Definition
Equation without an equality (=) or inequality (>,<)
I have also tried introducing booleans in an equation that resembles power == (can_on * key + (1-can_on) *b0 + can_off * 0 + (1-can_off) * key)/2. The booleans are controlled variables in the hysteresis_equation and are set to 1 or 0 depending on the state of hysteresis, but are not GEKKO variables.
Thank you in advance for your help.

please add a [mre] so that people willing to answer you can go straight to the point

@folengateis did my best to provide the example and clean up the question. I don't find there is a point in elaborating more, I am rather new to GEKKO and don't understand how to implement binary varaibles in it. Also, I can't go further in the problem solution without solving the implementation of hysteresis which is exaplained by the bullet points. Thank you for the remarks, hope the added details help.

The easiest way to prevent the controller from turning off or on MVs too frequently is to use the u.MV_STEP_HOR option to specify the number of steps that it must be constant before it can move again. More details are in the documentation.
Implementing a time-based condition is more complicated, but still possible. Below is an example script that has a minimum on-time of 2 cycles and a minimum off-time of 3 cycles. It uses logical conditions that switch the on_allow and off_allow states that control the inequality constraints on the MV derivative.

from gekko import GEKKO
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
from matplotlib.ticker import MaxNLocator 

m = GEKKO()
m.time = np.linspace(0,10,11)

min_on_time = 2
min_off_time = 3

# Manipulated variable
u = m.MV(0, lb=0, ub=1, integer=True)
uc = m.Var(0); m.Equation(uc==u) # copy variable
u.STATUS = 1  # allow optimizer to change

is_on = m.Intermediate(u) # m.if3(u-0.5,0,1)
is_off = m.Intermediate(1-is_on)

on_time,off_time = m.Array(m.Var,2,value=0)
m.Equation(on_time.dt()==is_on)
m.Equation(off_time.dt()==is_off)

on_td,off_td = m.Array(m.Var,2,value=0)
m.delay(on_time,on_td,min_on_time+1)
m.delay(off_time,off_td,min_off_time+1)

off_allow = m.if3(on_time -on_td -min_on_time +0.5,0,1)
on_allow  = m.if3(off_time-off_td-min_off_time+0.5,0,1)

m.Equation(off_allow *(uc.dt()+1)+ (1-off_allow) * uc.dt()>=0)
m.Equation( on_allow *(uc.dt()-1)+ (1-on_allow)  * uc.dt()<=0)

# Process model
x = m.Var(value=0,lb=0,ub=5)
m.Equation(5*x.dt() == -x + 3*u)

# Objective
m.Minimize((x-2)**2)

m.options.IMODE = 6 # control
m.options.SOLVER = 1
m.solve(disp=True)

plt.figure(figsize=(6,3.5))
plt.subplot(3,1,1)
plt.step(m.time,u.value,'b-',label='u Profile')
plt.plot(m.time,x.value,'r--',label='x Response')
plt.legend(); plt.grid()
ax = plt.gca()
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(MaxNLocator(integer=True))

plt.subplot(3,1,2)
plt.plot(m.time,on_allow.value,'r--',label='on allow')
plt.plot(m.time,off_allow.value,'k:',label='off allow')
ax = plt.gca()
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(MaxNLocator(integer=True))
plt.legend(); plt.grid()

plt.subplot(3,1,3)
plt.plot(m.time,on_time.value,'r--',label='on time')
plt.plot(m.time,off_time.value,'k:',label='off time')
ax = plt.gca()
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(MaxNLocator(integer=True))
plt.legend(); plt.grid()

plt.xlabel('Time'); plt.tight_layout()
plt.savefig('results.png',dpi=300)
plt.show()


Solution works well, however optimization times are very large. There was a problem given the non-linearity of the control in convergence towards a solution. I solved it by increasing the MAX_ITER and MAX_MEMORY to account for the complexity.
